# AES encryption in python invalid output

Tags: python, encryption, aes

I am writing a secure chat program in which uses AES-256 bit encryption, yesterday I was testing out different methods in AES, where the following worked, my program will allow the user to set the encryption key and the program will add or subtract however many characters are needed to have a 32 byte key. Now when I saved the following code yesterday it worked, however, today when I run through the terminal I get this invalid output, but when I run the program from yesterday, It gives me the correct output!! Anyone who would be able to help, that would be great

```
>>> import Crypto
>>> from Crypto.Cipher import AES
>>> iv = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
>>> key = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
>>> cipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CFB, iv)
>>> cipher.encrypt('Hello')
'c\x0f\x81\xc4\xde'
>>> cipher.decrypt('c\x0f\x81\xc4\xde')
'\x88\xd4;YR'
```

Comment: Reinitialize the IV.

Comment: The IV must be different (read: random) for each encryption with the same key. Don't use a static IV, because that makes the cipher deterministic and permits the attacker to deduce the plaintexts if they observed multiple ciphertexts. This is called the many-time pad (or [two-time pad](https://twitter.com/angealbertini/status/425561082841690112/photo/1)). The IV is not secret, so you can send it along with the ciphertext. Usually, it is simply prepended to the ciphertext and sliced off before decryption.

Comment: The proper advice would be to not even use `AES`.

Comment: Why is that? @AnttiHaapala it is working with AES-256 now, is there another encryption I should use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because reusing the AES state and the AES state was now mutated. You need to create a new state:

```
Python 3.5.3 (default, Jan 19 2017, 14:11:04) 
>>> from Crypto.Cipher import AES
>>> iv = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
>>> iv = b'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
>>> key = b'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
>>> cipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CFB, iv)
>>> cipher.encrypt('Hello')
b'c\x0f\x81\xc4\xde'
>>> cipher.decrypt(b'c\x0f\x81\xc4\xde')
b'\x88\xd4;YR'
```

Do not reuse the state, but create a new one freshly initialized from the IV.

```
>>> cipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CFB, iv)
>>> cipher.decrypt(b'c\x0f\x81\xc4\xde')
b'Hello'
```